# Подсчитать количество повторений в значениях словаря внутри списка python

Tags: python, list, словари

Дан список учеников, нужно посчитать количество повторений каждого имени ученика.

```
students = [
    {'first_name': 'Вася'},
    {'first_name': 'Петя'},
    {'first_name': 'Маша'},
    {'first_name': 'Маша'},
    {'first_name': 'Петя'},
    ]
```

Пример вывода:
Вася: 1
Маша: 2
Петя: 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант можно извлечь имена в временную переменную `temp`

```
from collections import Counter

temp = [i['first_name'] for i in students]
for k, v in Counter(temp).items():
    print(f'{k}: {v}')
```